# getting error in image tag in react js tsx file

Tags: reactjs, tsx

when i try to give style attribute in tsx file for image tag, i am getting below error

```
Replace `'backgroundColor'·:·'red'·}}·/>··` with `backgroundColor:·'red'·}}·/>
```

here is my image tag which i am using

```
<img src={Caeser} width="50" style={{ 'backgroundColor' : 'red' }} />
```

can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ? any help will be really appreciated, is there anything missing from my side ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `''` of `backgroundColor` like this:

```
<img src={Caeser} width="50" style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
```

Comment: then getting this error Line 362:60:  Replace `·:·'red'·}}·/>·` with `:·'red'·}}·/>`

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use extension auto format code when save file